# Spacing between points in graph in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

[image: 3D graph]

As can be seen in the picture attached, the points become too cluttered after a certain point. How do I increase the spacing between points in that region?
Code:

```
set term jpeg size 1800,900
set output "plot.jpeg"

splot "3d_ME2_31.out" us 1:2:3 lc -1 

set grid

set output
```

I have tried the "every" command but it increasing the spacing in the beginning region too where the point spacing is already high.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks !

Edit: Data file ( the data to axes mapping is 1:2:3 )

```
0.94652E+03    0.46588E+02    0.82952E-01
0.94871E+03    0.61601E+02    0.16795E+00
0.95102E+03    0.74087E+02    0.29030E+00
0.95587E+03    0.94012E+02    0.65911E+00
0.95850E+03    0.10204E+03    0.91894E+00
0.96148E+03    0.10885E+03    0.12599E+01
0.96515E+03    0.11542E+03    0.17353E+01
0.96943E+03    0.12040E+03    0.23543E+01
0.97481E+03    0.12578E+03    0.32153E+01
0.98134E+03    0.13077E+03    0.43582E+01
0.98901E+03    0.13507E+03    0.58196E+01
0.99795E+03    0.13948E+03    0.76562E+01
0.10082E+04    0.14377E+03    0.99270E+01
0.10199E+04    0.14800E+03    0.12677E+02
0.10282E+04    0.14775E+03    0.14762E+02
0.10335E+04    0.14413E+03    0.16176E+02
0.10403E+04    0.14050E+03    0.18096E+02
0.10488E+04    0.13621E+03    0.20616E+02
0.10588E+04    0.13205E+03    0.23729E+02
0.10710E+04    0.12798E+03    0.27711E+02
0.10843E+04    0.12370E+03    0.32248E+02
0.10995E+04    0.11973E+03    0.37684E+02
0.11163E+04    0.11572E+03    0.43955E+02
0.11324E+04    0.11203E+03    0.50189E+02
0.11474E+04    0.10875E+03    0.56245E+02
0.11626E+04    0.10553E+03    0.62585E+02
0.11781E+04    0.10217E+03    0.69305E+02
0.11938E+04    0.99038E+02    0.76322E+02
0.12094E+04    0.96412E+02    0.83573E+02
0.12252E+04    0.94002E+02    0.91126E+02
0.12411E+04    0.91794E+02    0.98981E+02
0.12571E+04    0.89765E+02    0.10714E+03
0.12732E+04    0.87918E+02    0.11559E+03
0.12894E+04    0.86536E+02    0.12432E+03
0.13054E+04    0.84701E+02    0.13318E+03
0.13213E+04    0.82945E+02    0.14227E+03
0.13373E+04    0.81284E+02    0.15161E+03
0.13533E+04    0.79678E+02    0.16122E+03
0.13694E+04    0.78071E+02    0.17111E+03
0.13855E+04    0.76542E+02    0.18127E+03
0.14008E+04    0.74960E+02    0.19118E+03
0.14159E+04    0.73330E+02    0.20115E+03
0.14309E+04    0.71898E+02    0.21132E+03
0.14458E+04    0.70357E+02    0.22162E+03
0.14607E+04    0.68300E+02    0.23218E+03
0.14758E+04    0.66454E+02    0.24304E+03
0.14907E+04    0.64530E+02    0.25400E+03
0.15055E+04    0.62676E+02    0.26517E+03
0.15204E+04    0.60999E+02    0.27663E+03
0.15354E+04    0.59429E+02    0.28833E+03
0.15500E+04    0.57764E+02    0.30002E+03
0.15641E+04    0.56109E+02    0.31144E+03
0.15758E+04    0.53850E+02    0.32117E+03
0.15882E+04    0.51118E+02    0.33162E+03
0.16010E+04    0.48445E+02    0.34255E+03
0.16127E+04    0.45813E+02    0.35263E+03
0.16249E+04    0.43266E+02    0.36339E+03
0.16373E+04    0.40811E+02    0.37449E+03
0.16498E+04    0.38485E+02    0.38581E+03
0.16620E+04    0.36479E+02    0.39707E+03
0.16742E+04    0.34549E+02    0.40846E+03
0.16860E+04    0.32632E+02    0.41963E+03
```

Comment: Please show the commands used to create the plot.  Is this a function? Data from a file? The result of a "fit" operation?

Comment: @Ethan It's data from a file. I have edited in the code now.

Comment: @D.Mason could you please provide the data as text? This would then be a complete reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example What is your gnuplot version?

Comment: @theozh Hi. I have provided the data. The gnuplot version is 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say whether your data points look cluttered or cramped does not only depend on your data but also on your viewpoint.
If you have so many data points why don't you simply plot it `with lines`? Or as Ethan suggested `with linespoints` and a certain `pointinterval` or `pointnumber` (check `help lp`).

**Script:**

```
set multiplot layout 2,1

    set view 60,30
    splot $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 1

    set view 71,333
    splot $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 1
unset multiplot
```

**Result:** (same datapoints just different viewing angles)

[image]

Comment: I cannot plot it with lines because I will be plotting multiple data sets in the same graph and they will overlap.

Comment: @D.Mason what about different colors? So, as I understand: lines would overlap, but not the points? Maybe you want to modify your question (and data) to show the "real" problem?

Answer (score 1):

It would be complicated to limit the point reduction to a certain region, but you can do it globally using the `pointinterval` property of the style `with linespoints`.   If you want to hide the line you can set the linetype to "nodraw":   `with linespoints lt nodraw pi 5`. But that would get you back to the same result as using `every` to filter the points. The nice thing about using pointinterval instead is that the line goes through all the points even though not all of them are shown.  So a jog in the line can highlight an outlier that might otherwise be hidden.

```
#Plot every 5th point
splot 'DATA' with linespoints pointinterval 5
```

[image]